# Android custom image gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gridview

I want to create an image gallery that will load images from the **SDCARD**. The gallery should look similar to the image shown below

[image]

So that when clicking on the left image, the respective large image will be shown in the right. I know its possible to do so, I can setup a GridView with a single column and assign an id to each image so that when clicking on the image on the left, an event will trigger to get the selected image ID and then load the respective image from SDCARD to show on the left.

Am I heading towards the right direction or someone will help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this website [androidview.net](http://www.androidviews.net/) it contains many GUI solutions and you might find one that fits your needs/alternative.

As for displaying images from sdcard, [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard) can help you.
good luck